# Firebase Storage: Public to Internet about files under a specific directory

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to publish all the files under a specific directory to the Internet.

Security Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /public/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

After writing the security rules as described above, when I open the Browser of Cloud Storage:

- The files under the directory are still set to private.
- If you look at the details of each file, you will see that no public URL has been issued.

[image]

And when I enter the `Authenticated URL`, you will be redirected to Google's login page.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase security rules only control who can get the URL of a specific object either by Firebase SDK or REST APIs. If you check for object URL in Firebase console, you'll see an URL of format which is probably what you are looking for:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[PROJECT].appspot.com/o/public%2Fdog.jpg?alt=media&token=fd991fdf-a33f-4321-9017-09907e1a5243
```

Security rules can only restrict users from getting this URL at first place however anyone with this URL can access the image/file (if an authorized user has shared the URL).

That being said, the rule `allow read: if true;` will allow anyone to get the public (like the one shown above) and they can access it.

---

If you want a public link from GCS as well then you would have to edit permissions from GCP console and allow `allUsers` to read it:

[image]

Comment: So the security rule is not to issue a public URL, but only to set the range of Authenticated URL. Thank you.  
  
However, after setting the above security rule, when I open the Authenticated URL of a file under public with an unauthenticated browser, I am redirected to the Google login page.  
This looks to me like the security rule `allow read: if true;` is not applied.

Comment: @kusumoto_teruya the authenticated URL is different... you should check the URL in Firebase console or get one using Firebase SDK as mentioned  here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just noticed that when I opened the file details, the "Name" field was made into a link. So we can use this URL.